# access state of react component from other component

Tags: reactjs

I have the following spinner

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import './Spinner.scss'

export default class Spinner extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {showLoading: true};
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <div className="spinner">
        <div className="double-bounce1"></div>
        <div className="double-bounce2"></div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

and from other component I would like to show or hide this spinner here is the code of the component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

import RTable from '../../../components/RTable/RTable'

import Spinner from '../../../components/Spinner/Spinner'

import CsvDownload from '../containers/CsvDownloadContainer'
export default class Table extends Component {

  _renderBreadcrumb () {
    const { breadcrumb, handleBreadcrumbClick } = this.props
    return (
      <ol className="breadcrumb">
        {(breadcrumb || []).map(el => {
          return (
            <li key={el.datasetKey}>
              <a onClick={() => { handleBreadcrumbClick(el.granularity, el.datasetKey, el.datasetKeyHuman) }}>
                {el.datasetKeyHuman}
              </a>
            </li>
          )
        })}
      </ol>
    )
  }

  render () {
    const { datasetRows, columns, metadata, showLoading } = this.props

    return (
      <div className="row">
        <div className="col-sm-12">
          {this._renderBreadcrumb()}
          <RTable rows={datasetRows} columns={columns} metadata={metadata} />
          { this.props.showLoading ? <Spinner /> : null }
          <CsvDownload />
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }

}
```

as you can see I trying to show or hide the spinner using:

```
{ this.props.showLoading ? <Spinner /> : null }
```

but I'm always getting undefinde. Some help please.

Answer (score 2):

You have to move this

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {showLoading: true};
}
```

to your `<Table />` component, otherwise you access `showLoading` from `<Table />'s props`, but it is not passed from anywhere.

Then change also

```
{ this.props.showLoading ? <Spinner /> : null }
```

to

```
{ this.state.showLoading ? <Spinner /> : null }
```

To show / hide `<Spinner />` just call `this.setState({ showLoading: Boolean })` in your `<Table />` component.